# find var value by name not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the following code I want to get the id value,

in the field $rowData I've property which is called id(lower case) and I want 
to get the value of the id,I read about it in SO and tried many things but I was not able to 
get the id value,any idea what am I missing here?

```
var $rowData = getData($delRow);
entryId = $rowData.find("id").val();
```

I 've tried also with

```
$(rowData).prop("id");
```

and I got error for undefied ...any idea what am I missing here ?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: yeah please provide fiddle

Comment: `getData` returns jquery object?

Comment: have you tried using attr?. e.g: $(rowData).attr('id')

Comment: @HolgerTans, did you mean? $rowData.prop("id");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try like following:

```
entryId = $delRow.data("id");
```

Check it and let me know.

Good luck!